# Setting React Element Focus Dynamically without Arrow Function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, arrow-functions, currying

I currently have the following code that works very well:

```
import React, {
  RefObject,
  useReducer,
  useRef,
  useState
} from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
    const input1Ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
    const input2Ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
    const [focusedElRef, setFocusedElRef] = useState<RefObject<HTMLInputElement>>(startDateRef);

  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        inputRef={input1Ref}
        autoFocus={true}
        onFocus={() => setFocusedElRef(input1Ref)}
      />
      <TextField
        inputRef={input2Ref}
        onFocus={() => setFocusedElRef(input2Ref)}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is there a way I can use a value automatically returned from the `onFocus` method that indicates input reference that I can use in another arrow function to call `setFocusedElRef` correctly?

**UPDATE: NOV. 5, 2019**

I also need to later check in the code if an input is in focus by using `if (focusedElRef === input1Ref)` for example.

I know that this optimization is quite worthless, but I'm still curious.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one onFocus function and maintain only one current focused element in state:

Created example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-73hmm

Comment: Thank you, but then how would I check if the current input is in focus? Sorry I wasn't clear about this point, I updated my question.

Comment: You have focusedEl that is current or last that was focused of you want to check if in focus now :  https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-zhl7v focusedEl === document.activeElement